# Domain for partner_shipping_id showing the child_ids of partner_id - Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-14

I would like to ovewrite `partner_shipping_id` field in `sale.order` to only display contacs from `res.partner` that match `partner_id`. Currently shows all existing contacts, so I would like to change this behavior.

This is what I tried:

```py
 partner_shipping_id = fields.Many2one(
        'res.partner', 
        string='Delivery Address', 
        readonly=True, 
        required=True,
        states={
            'draft': [('readonly', False)], 
            'sent': [('readonly', False)], 
            'sale': [('readonly', False)]},
        domain="[('child_ids.parent_id','=', partner_id)]"
        # domain=
        # "['|', ('company_id', '=', False), ('company_id', '=', company_id)]",
        )
```

But this only returns the same selected record in `parnter_id` field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To show only partner contacts, use the following domain:

```
domain="[('parent_id', '=', partner_id)]"
```

***Example:***

```
<record id="sale_order_form_only_partner_contacts" model="ir.ui.view">
<field name="name">sale.order.form.only.partner.contacts</field>
<field name="model">sale.order</field>
<field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/>
<field name="arch" type="xml">
    <field name="partner_shipping_id" position="attributes">
        <attribute name="domain">[('parent_id', '=', partner_id)]</attribute>
    </field>
</field>
</record>
```